# Forceably set permissions when running rsync

Tags: server, command-line, permissions, backup, rsync

Currently I am backing up gigabytes and gigabytes of data from a live server to a backup server using an rsync/ssh combination script, allowing for automated operation every night with a cron job.

The problem I am having is with permissions.

Running rsync with -a mode copies over the user:group and filemode, which are currently 54122:games and -rwx--S---.

In order to be able to execute the files on the backup server (don't ask me why the employer requires this), I've had to run a time- and cpu-costly (because of the sheer amount of data transferred) chown() and chmod() setting every file/folder to www-data:www-data and permissions of 755.

Is there anyway I can setup rsync to forcibly set each file/folder to www-data:www-data and 755 or am I looking at this problem from the wrong angle?

I guess I could run -rltD instead of -a (which is equivalent to -rlptgoD) but then what happens to new files? What permissions and owner:group settings do they receive?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Amongst many other options [rsync](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/rsync.1.html) can change permission by running it with the option:

```
rsync [options] --chmod=CHMOD source destination
```

where you can also combine option `--archive` with the option `--no-owner` or `--no-perms` to exclude preservation of owner resp. permissions. For further options on very subtle settings for CHMOD see the [manpage for rsync](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/rsync.1.html).

Comment: Note that the `--perms` flag is required to get the above command to work. Also, though I didn't try, I assume the `--no-perms` flag will not work, it will most likely disable the `--chmod` flag.

Comment: Example: `rsync --chmod=ugo=rX source/ destination/`

Comment: Another example: `rsync --chmod=764 source/ destination/`

Answer (score 2):

If the permissions are already setup that way on the machine you are copying from you could try -p.  It saves the permissions.  Also you may want to try grsync.  It's a gui for rsync that makes some of the options more apparent.  Also -o preserves the owner.

Hope that helps.  Good luck.